# How can i open an Akka project using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, akka

i am trying to create a simple hello-akka project using the typesafe activator. I have everything working and the project even runs in the typesafe tab. I clicked on create eclipse project, and some files are added to my directory but i cannot figure out how to open them and run the file in eclipse!

These are the files i currently have in the directory:

1. .sbtserver
2. project
3. src
4. target
5. gitignore
6. (GITIGNORE FILE?)
7. activator.bat and activator.jar
8. build.sbt

In another workspace i tried creating my own scala project, by adding akka-actor.jar to the libary but i get the following error :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'ActorSystem.class'. Could not access term typesafe in package com, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.) A full rebuild may help if 'ActorSystem.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.    tst     Unknown Scala Problem
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few dependencies you'll need to find and add if you're determined to make this work -- a scala-library, for example. It's better to find a way to integrate your build with your IDE if you can -- this will allow the IDE to find dependencies the same way the build does -- and in this case, the build system is SBT.

The easiest path forward may be to download [ScalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org/), which is a Scala specific package for Eclipse. This should come ready to go with support for SBT projects. Most Actor/Scala devs I know use IntelliJ or ScalaIDE.

Another option would be to use the SBT plugin for Eclipse, but in my experience it tends to be unreliable, changing with far less frequency than the IDE itself. If you install it and it doesn't look like it's working, you're probably right.

Finally, you can ditch SBT for Gradle or Maven and then use the Gradle or Maven plugins for Eclipse. If you have either of those in your shop already this is likely something you will need to do down the road, anyway. SBT is a good build system but nowhere near as feature rich as Gradle or ubiquitous as Maven.